# Every plane projective conic is normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve exercise I.$3.17$ a) from Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, which states that every conic $X\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ is normal.

By definition $X$ is normal $\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{P,X}$ is integrally closed for every $P\in X$. Since this is a local property, I can think of $X$ as an affine conic.

I've tried to look at the specific example $X=Z(y-x^2)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ to see if it helps.

Since $\overline{y}=\overline{x}^2\in A(X)$, then for any $f\in k[x,y]$ we get:
$$f(\overline{x},\overline{y})=f(\overline{x},\overline{x}^2)=\prod_{i=1}^k(\overline{x}-a_i)$$

for some constants $a_i\in k$, since $k$ is algebraically closed.

This shows $A(X)$ is a UFD, and in particular integrally closed.

I'm sure this argument won't work for a general conic, so I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is exercise 3.17a). I couldn’t edit it as it is too short. I think you can use Exercise I.1.1c) as those two rings in the exercise are normal.

Comment: @Youngsu I've just corrected it, thank you